# Bond price formula, redemption yield and no arbitrage

Tags: finance-mathematics

Given the 1 year bond  with a price 98 and C as 8% on face value 100. 
I want to find the implied single compounding interest rate. 
I can solve for r via the bond price formula or I can just set up the equation 98(1+r)=106 and solve for r and it will be the same. 
However I do not 100% understand why this is the case. Is it because we are assuming no arbitrage and the redemption yield is the current prevailing market rate and thus, for example, a bank account must have this interest rate? 
Grateful for any answers